# How to uninstall android apps using the new PackageInstaller api?

Tags: android, uninstallation, packageinstaller

The old way of uninstalling android apps with `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` is deprecated in API level 29. Now it's recommended to use `PackageInstaller.uninstall(packageName: String, statusReceiver: IntentSender)` instead. This is what a came-up with so far:

```
fun uninstal(){
    val packageName = "some package name"
    val packageInstaller = this.packageManager.packageInstaller
    val intent = Intent(this, this::class.java)
    val sender = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)
    packageInstaller.uninstall(packageName, sender.intentSender) 
}
```

I cannot figure out how to provide the `IntentSender`. I tried to make an intent from and to the current activity but all this code does is recreate the activity. Any idea please? and thanks

Comment: "I tried to make an intent from and to the current activity but all this code does is recreate the activity" -- then perhaps use `getBroadcast()` and route to a `BroadcastReceiver`. We do not know what you are looking to do when the uninstall operation is finished.

Comment: Well normally when one try to uninstall an app, a popup window appears prompting to user whether to uninstall the app or to cancel but in this case nothing happens

Comment: I think that `IntentSender` is for the end result, not for the user confirmation. The user confirmation would be raised by the OS. Do you have permission to uninstall packages?

Comment: Yes, I added the necessary permissions as specified in the documentation but still nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intent based method still works on API Level 29+ devices. Just change your Intent action to

> Intent.ACTION_DELETE

Also you need to add the permission to delete packages as well.

> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES"/>

Here is the complete code :

```
val pkg             = "package_to_delete" 
val uri: Uri        = Uri.fromParts("package", pkg, null)
val uninstallIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri)

startActivityForResult(uninstallIntent, EXIT_REQUEST)
```

In the above code, pkg is the packageName of the App you want to delete in string format and EXIT_REQUEST is an Integer value.